# How can Bond Albedo be greater than Geometric Albedo?

Tags: albedo

Have gathered from papers like this one (*) that "Albedo is differentiated into two general types: (1) normal, reflective or geometric albedo, and (2) bond albedo". The document explained that Geometric Albedo usually is bigger than the Bond Albedo, which often just reflects two-thirds of the reflective light of Geometric Albedo.

Wikipedia points out in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_albedo) article about Bond Albedo; that Bond Albedo sometimes  can be greater than Geometric Albedo, which apparently is the case with Venus and Mars.

Question is; How Is this possible? What is behind this phenomenon? I think Wikipedia is trying to explain it, but I have difficulty grasping it. Can it be explained in an easier way? Examples with pictures would be ideal.

(*) "Background Reading to Albedo Investigation" (Google this document title)

Comment: There's an interesting and potentially helpful discussion in Zephyr's answer to [Why is Enceladus's albedo greater than 1?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20795)

Comment: Not my field, but based on your link, A (bond albedo) = p*q where p is the geometric albedo and q is the phase integral.  So, if q < 1.0, then geometric > Bond.  If q > 1.0, geometric < Bond.